# How to store and log for all http request and response in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, logging

I want to store all outgoing http request from my wordpress site. I want to store all internal and external http request and response also request made with curl. Any help should be useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hook into `WP_Http::_dispatch_request()`

```php
function fn_log_http_request_response( $wp_http_response, $request, $url ) {
    $request = [
        'method' => $request['method'],
        'url' => $url,
        'headers' => $request['headers'],
        'body' => $request['body'],
    ];

    if($wp_http_response instanceof WP_Error) {
        $response = [
            'errors' => $wp_http_response->errors,
            'error_data' => $wp_http_response->error_data,
        ];
    } else {
        $response = [
            'status' => [
                'code' => wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($wp_http_response),
                'message' => wp_remote_retrieve_response_message($wp_http_response),
            ],
            'headers' => wp_remote_retrieve_headers($wp_http_response)->getAll(),
            'body' => wp_remote_retrieve_body($wp_http_response),
        ];
    }

    error_log(print_r([
        'request' => $request,
        'response' => $response,
    ], true));

    return $wp_http_response;
}

// hook into WP_Http::_dispatch_request()
add_filter('http_response', 'fn_log_http_request_response', 10, 3 );
```

Adopted from [**hinnerk-a**](https://gist.github.com/hinnerk-a/2846011)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following plugin as well

https://wordpress.org/plugins/log-http-requests

Comment: It seems it has XSS vulnerability in all versions prior to and including 1.3.1. See here https://bishopfox.com/blog/log-http-requests-advisory#:~:text=Log%20HTTP%20Requests%20is%20a,%2Flog%2Dhttp%2Drequests.